# При умножении двух переменных получаю ноль

Tags: python

```py
price_hotel = input("Введите стоимость одной ночи в отеле:")

price_hotel = int()

days = input('Введите количество дней отдыха:')

days = int()

total = int(price_hotel * days)

print('Стоимость отдыха: ', price_hotel * days)
```

когда вводишь данные, например `2800` и `5`, программа умножая выдает `0`

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Оберните свои инпуты в инт. То что вы делаете не преобразоывает, а переназначает переменные price_hotel, days

Comment: Давно здесь не был, хватит минусы ставить! Обратите внимание ТС в комментраиях как исправить вопрос, чтобы он соответствовал правилам сообщества и вашим ожиданиям!

Comment: @Dmitry, но это не значит, что не надо ставить минусы...

Comment: @Глеб так напишите комментарий, правильные вы наши. Человек только пришел и вы тут сразу ему минусов наваливаете, а ТС даже не понимает почему...

Comment: а как же самоутверждаться, не ставя минусы? )))

Answer (score 3):

```
print("Введите стоимость одной ночи в отеле:")

price_hotel = int(input())

print('Введите количество дней отдыха:')

days = int(input())

total = price_hotel * days

print('Стоимость отдыха: ', str(total))
```

Попробую ответить.

Вы делаете запрос ввода `price_hotel` в строке, потом меняете его на целое число `price_hotel = int()`.

Пайтон  "не понимает", то есть Вы вводите 2800, а потом это число превращаете в 0 функцией `int()`.

Следовательно ответ у вас и получается 0. А так пайтон принимает только строки, в выводе на экран, ответ нужно преобразовать в строку, функцией `str()`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы переназначаете переменные `price_hotel` и `days`. Для того чтобы преобразовать переменные в целочисленный тип, просто оберните в `int()` ваши инпуты, здесь чтобы было понятно код

```py
price_hotel = input("Введите стоимость одной ночи в отеле:")

price_hotel = int(price_hotel)

days = input('Введите количество дней отдыха:')

days = int(days)

print('Стоимость отдыха: ', price_hotel * days)
```

Здесь код, который также понятен и будет иметь ту же функциональность

```py
price_hotel = int(input("Введите стоимость одной ночи в отеле:"))

days = int(input('Введите количество дней отдыха:'))

print('Стоимость отдыха: ', price_hotel * days)
```

PS обратите внимание на справку, там прочитайте как задавать вопросы. Не обращайте внимание на минусы без причины

Comment: Пример плохого ответа: тупо код, без объяснений почему надо так.

Comment: @Эникейщик согласен, но отметьте другой ответ

Comment: @Эникейщик лучше? =)

Comment: ну так-то получше!

Comment: Гм. Для чего вам строчка `total = int(price_hotel * days)`?

Comment: @АлексейР копи паст